# Add arrows to 'Cycle2' which cycle through several thumbnails at a time, rather than change the main image

Tags: jquery, gallery, thumbnails, cycle

I have a gallery with 5 thumbnails at the bottom (around 40 photos in total). And I have 'prev' and 'next' arrows either side of the thumbnails.

These 'prev' and 'next' arrows simply cycle through the images one by one.

Is it possible through Cycle2 to add 'prev' and 'next' arrows which when clicked, show the next 5 thumbnails, which can then be clicked to change the main image.

Much like the thumbnails on http://gravitymovie.warnerbros.com/#/gallery (if you hover near the bottom of the screen you will see the thumbnails where the arrows cycle through a set at a time)

Many thanks. Everything else is set up. Just cant seem to find this function!

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need the Cycle2 [carousel plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php)

Comment: Thanks, that has been implemented, but you only have the option to cycle one thumbnail at a time, rather than cycle 5 at a time using arrows... I don't think it's a feature of this carousel. Frustrating really as no user wants to cycle through one thumbnail at a time, clicking x number of times!

Comment: So you just need to declare your own prev/next events using the api. go [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/) and look at the EVENTS section. Find the `currSlide` index (under MISC BITS section) add 5 (or subtract) then use the `goto` command (under COMMANDS section) to advance to that slide.